# Angular 9 Add new item to list without refreshing list

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

I am developing an anglular application and I can say I am kind of new at angular. In my application I am binding data from server via httpclient with an observable array to a basic list like below. And I add a new item to list at different component. The both list component and adding new item components are at same page.

I have no problem with binding data and adding new one. I am getting problem after I add a new item. After I add new item to data source of list, the whole component getting refresh; but I don't want this, I want to add new element without refreshing list.

The simplified codes is here. 
My component that contain list:

```
 export class GroupSetupComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSet$: Observable<Group[]>;

  constructor (private groupService : GroupService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getGroups();
  } 

  getGroups() {
    this.dataSet$ = this.groupService.getGroups();
  }

  refreshGroupList(group: Group) {
    if(group) {
      // I have tried getting all list from database again
      // this.getGroups();

      // than I tried to add new item to existing observable array
      this.dataSet$ = this.dataSet$.
      pipe(
        map(data =>
          {
            data.push(group);
            return dataSet;
          }));
    }
  }
}
```

And component template:

```
<div *ngIf="dataSet$ | async as resultSet;">
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        <mat-selection-list>
            <mat-list-option *ngFor="let item of resultSet;" [value]="item.id" [disableRipple]="true">
                {{item.name}}
            </mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card></div>
```

The *refreshGroupList* function is triggering from child component after new item added to database and getting success message from api.

I want to ask , the way I am doing is right or not?  If not what is the efficient way to doing this kind of crud operations on a list?

Comment: Maybe you want to use trackBy? See this article: https://medium.com/better-programming/improving-angular-ngfor-performance-through-trackby-ae4cf943b878

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this to your component

```
   byId(index, item) {
      return item.id;
   }
```

and modify the ngFor

```
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let item of resultSet; trackBy: byId" [value]="item.id" [disableRipple]="true">
                {{item.name}}
            </mat-list-option>
```

By providing a trackBy key, angular will check each item and do the diff by ID instead of refreshing entire array. If you open up developer tool and inspect element you will notice only newly added item will get the dom update.

UPDATE---- 
You can try change your implementation like below, so you stream reference remain unchanged, see if that solves the problem

```
dataSet$=new BehaviorSubject([])
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getGroups().subscribe(group=>dataSet$.next(group));
  } 

refreshGroupList(group){
     this.dataSet$.next(this.dataSet$.value.concat(group))
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I think this is the point; but unfortunately it is still refreshing list after adding new item. Is using async pipe and observable effect something ?

Comment: dataSet$ is my real datasource, and I am adding item to this property, not resultSet. how this effect?

Comment: does dataSet$ return falsy sometimes or it always produce items? in theory it shouldn't be affected by *ngIf unless it goes from false to true and true to false etc.

Comment: I don't think so it goes from false to true . is in refreshGroupList function everything is ok? I am basically just adding a new item to current list there.

Comment: Your refreshGroupList is not an ideal solution but it still should not cause the entire list to refresh. you can try out behavior subject implementation

Comment: I think this.dataSet$ = this.dataSet$.pipe(//codes) assignment may cause the problem. It may change the reference of the all items by reassigning. I will have a look behaviour subject, do you have any source to recommend or some samples ?

Comment: what is getGroup() is it a http call ?

Comment: Yes it is, getGroups(): Observable<Group[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Group[]>(this.url);
   }

Comment: i updated answer with an alternative approach. please take a look

Comment: Thanks that worked. great work. I have some more questions ,deos the same approach works if I get whole list from database again and concat it with current dataset? And at the ngOnInit how can I sort the data list ?

Comment: as long as you manage to keep the same observable variable reference in template, it should be ok

Answer (score 0):

You can set on component `ChangeDetection: OnPush` and manualy tell when component should be refreshed by using ChangeDetecionRef service and method `markToCheck()`.